# Remove the parent div if child div is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to remove the whole parent div if it doesn't have the `wc-gallery` class on it. What I have in my script is the reverse of what I need. Basically it hide everything that has the `wc-gallery` on it.

SCRIPT:

```
// Additional Scripts
$(window).load( function() { 
    $(".gallery-container2 .gallery-item .wc-gallery").hide();
});
$(".gallery-container2 p").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $("[data-id=" + id + "].gallery-item .wc-gallery").toggle()
});


$(function(){
    $(".gallery-item").each(function(){
        $(this).children('.wc-gallery').parents('.gallery-container2').hide();
    });
});
```

Basically this will work fine if I Hide all the containers and display the child div afterwards though my content won't render due to script conflicts. Only way to solve this without conflict is to load first all of the containers then `hide()` or `remove()` them.

SCRIPT: (conflict due to onload content rendering)

```
$('.gallery-container2').hide();
$(function(){
    $(".gallery-item").each(function(){
        $(this).children('.wc-gallery').parents('.gallery-container2').show();
    });
});
```

HTML: (1st set is the one should be visible 2nd set is the one that needs to be remove or hide.)

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="gallery-container2">
        <p data-id="1723"><strong>some text</strong></p>
        <div class="gallery-item" data-id="1723">
            <div class="wc-gallery" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="gallery-container2">
        <p data-id="2455"><strong>View before and after</strong></p>
        <strong></strong>
        <div class="gallery-item" data-id="2455">
            <div><div></div></div>
        </div>
    </div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the '.gallery-container2' element and find out whether it has '.wc-gallery' children. if not hide the element.

```
$('.gallery-container2').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    //find element with 'wc-gallery' class
    var hasGallery = $this.find('.wc-gallery').length > 0;

    if(!hasGallery){
        $this.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want to compress it 

`$('.gallery-container2').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('.wc-gallery').length === 0){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});`

Answer (score 2):

Pure JS you might do like this in ES6 terms.

```js
var divsToHide = document.querySelectorAll("div div :not(.wc-gallery)");
for (var div of divsToHide) div.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div class="gallery-container2">
  <p data-id="1723"><strong>some text</strong>
  </p>
  <div class="gallery-item" data-id="1723">
    <div class="wc-gallery">first container</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery-container2">
  <p data-id="1724"><strong>some text</strong>
  </p>
  <div class="gallery-item" data-id="1724">
    <div>
      <div>second container</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. If div has children with class `.wc-gallery` than it will show the parent otherwise hide the parent.

```
$(function () {
   $(".gallery-item").each(function () {
     if($(this).children('.wc-gallery').length > 0)
       $(this).parents('.gallery-container2').show();
     else
       $(this).parents('.gallery-container2').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Edited the HTML. `wc-gallery` is on `hide()` onload

Comment: It doesn' matter it will just show the div if  `.wc-gallery` is there.

Comment: @MichaelPon jsut give this answer a try.

Comment: This hides all the container.

Comment: I copied all of your code and it is working fine. PLease see console if there is any error,